# (Python 3.x and SQL) Check if entries exists in multiple tables and convert to binary values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a 'master table' that contains just one column of ids from all my other tables. I also have several other tables that contain some of the ids, along with other columns of data. I am trying to iterate through all of the ids for each smaller table, create a new column for the smaller table, check if the id exists on that table and create a binary entry in the master table. (0 if the id doesn't exist, and 1 if the id does exist on the specified table)

That seems pretty confusing, but the application of this is to check if a user exists on the table for a specific date, and keep track of this information day to day.

Right now my I am iterating through the dates, and inside each iteration I am iterating through all of the ids to check if they exist for that date. This is likely going to be incredibly slow, and there is probably a better way to do this though. My code looks like this:

```
def main():
    dates = init()
    id_list = getids()
    print(dates)
    for date in reversed(dates):
        cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE " + table + " ADD " + date + " BIT;")
        cnx.commit()
        for ID in id_list:
            (...)
```

I know that the next step will be to generate a query using each id that looks something like:

```
SELECT id FROM [date]_table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master_table WHERE master_table.id = [date]_table.id)
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple days and so far I cannot come up with a query that gives a useful result.

.

For an example, if I had three tables for three days...

Monday:

```
+------+-----+
|  id  | ... |
+------+-----+
| 1001 | ... |
| 1002 | ... |
| 1003 | ... |
| 1004 | ... |
| 1005 | ... |
+------+-----+
```

Tuesday:

```
+------+-----+
|  id  | ... |
+------+-----+
| 1001 | ... |
| 1003 | ... |
| 1005 | ... |
+------+-----+
```

Wednesday:

```
+------+-----+
|  id  | ... |
+------+-----+
| 1002 | ... |
| 1004 | ... |
+------+-----+
```

I'd like to end up with a master table like this:

```
+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  id  | monday | tuesday | wednesday |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1001 |      1 |       1 |         0 |
| 1002 |      1 |       0 |         1 |
| 1003 |      1 |       1 |         0 |
| 1004 |      1 |       0 |         1 |
| 1005 |      1 |       1 |         0 |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Thank you ahead of time for any help with this issue. And since it's sort of a confusing problem, please let me know if there are any additional details I can provide.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403144/fast-way-to-check-for-matching-ids-in-master-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way to check for matching ID's in master table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403144/fast-way-to-check-for-matching-ids-in-master-table)