# Fast way to check for matching ID's in master table?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a SQL database with a 'master table' containing only the IDs from the rest of the tables in the database. (Duplicates have already been handled.) I want to iterate through each of the rest of the tables in my database, adding a column to the 'master table' and then adding a '1' to the column if each ID from the 'master table' exists in the small list, and adding a '0' otherwise.

I've tried a few queries so far but they seem pretty slow. The tables I am using will contain a few thousand IDs each so I'd like to find a fast method.

My Python code looks like this so far:

```
def main():
    table_list = init() #Gets a list of others tables in the database.
    for ltab in table_list:
        id_list = getids(ltab) #Gets the ids for each smaller table.
        cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE " + table + " ADD " + ltab + " BIT;")
        cnx.commit()
        for ID in id_list:
            (...)
```

What I would do next (as a beginner) would be to iterate through each ID and check it against the 'master table,' but I'm looking for a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with meta data, i prefer to use information_schema, so you will have a single query to fetch the data.

For Example:

```
#create table Test1(id_1 integer, title varchar(100));
#create table Test2(id_2 integer, title varchar(100));
#insert into Test1(id_1, title) values(1, "Hello");
#insert into Test2(id_2, title) values(1, "Hello");
#insert into Test1(id_1, title) values(2, "Hello");
#insert into Test2(id_2, title) values(2, "Hello");
select column_name,
       sum( if( TABLE_NAME = 'Test1', 1, 0 ) ) as Test1, 
       sum( if( TABLE_NAME = 'Test2', 1, 0 ) ) as Test2 
   from information_schema.columns
   where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema'
   and column_name like '%id%'
   group by column_name;
```

Will give you something like:

```
    column_name Test1   Test2
1   accepterid    0       0
2   acl_id        0       0
3   id_1          1       0
4   id_2          0       1
```

So in your above query you can tweak it as

```
_tables = ','.join([("sum( if( TABLE_NAME = '%s', 1, 0 ) ) as %s" % (i,i)) for i in table_list ])

query = """
        create view master as(
        select column_name, %s
         from information_schema.columns
         where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema'
         and column_name like '%id%'
         group by column_name;)
       """ % (_table,)
cursor.execute(query)
```